# What are these geological horizontal lines formed on this mountain called and why they are formed?

Tags: geology, mountains, stratigraphy, mountain-building

This images are of Mt. Kailash, Himalaya.

**Front face of Mount:**

[image]

**Back face of Mount:**

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_original_horizontality

Comment: @Universal_learner Thanks quite helpful. But this mount is the only mouth with this kind of formation in local mountain range. Is it possible?

Comment: We have in Spain many mountains that are some metters above the cities that are not folded. Just imagine a slice of butter is cutted and taked some milles away but not derformed

Comment: @Universal_learner Thank you so much! Your insight helped me a lot to understand this geology artifact.

Comment: Your question could be better if you include the location of the mountain. Is that Himalaya?

Comment: @Cicada why are you saying this is the only mountain with this? The two other mountains in the first picture have exactly the same thing on them.

Comment: @Universal_learner Yes, you are right, indeed it is Himalaya. I have included the exact name of moun.

Comment: @Gimelist due to camera angle it seems that they are 3 different mounts. But, in fact they are one single unit. Rest of the mounts in surrounding area don't have same resemblance with Mt. Kailash.

Comment: @Cicada The location is interesting. Some nice articles in the web about Kailash mountain and formation. That allowed me to find my mistake. They are indeed lacustrine sediments. They deposit horizontally as marine shelves. My pleasure to know about that mountain hoppe you obtained an answer. Welcome to ESSE!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you see are bedding surfaces. They formed horizontally in a sedimentary lacustrine environment, the Kailash Formation.

This is a reconstruction of the paleoenvironment:

[image].

([Source](https://thewire.in/the-sciences/is-mt-kailash-the-oldest-mountain-in-the-himalaya))

As Gimelist noted, the sedimentary layers formed above a magmatic body.

The question is why they reached an altitude of 8,000 meters and are still horizontal.

It is an extreme example of [the principle of original horizontality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_original_horizontality), which gives the polarity of succession. The materials above are newer than those below because they were deposited horizontally. The tectonic uplift didn't change the original horizontal arrangement.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on this point from the comments:

> But this mount is the only mouth with this kind of formation in local mountain range

First, the [image on the mountain's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Kailash#/media/File:Kailash-Barkha.jpg) page clearly shows that the surrounding mountains also have the horizontal layers.

The Wikipedia page also states that:

> Mount Kailash appears to be a metasedimentary roof pendant supported by a massive granite base.

The source links for that information are broken. In any case, what this means in plain language is that Earth's surface had sedimentary layers, which are very common, and magma intruded underneath it. This is also very common. For example, the Andes and Cascades mountain ranges in Western South and North America are places where this is happening these days. Over time, the mountains (Himalayas) were pushed upwards by the Indian continent collision, and the rocks eroded away such that the mountain shows the top of the granite, overlain by the bottom of the sedimentary rocks like this:

[image: Kailash geology]

This (paywalled) article has more information:
[Kailas: geology of a sacred mountain](https://doi.org/10.1046/j.1365-2451.1998.014002067.x)

Comment: I like when you add diagrams maden with pencils :). I guess Gangdese Arc basement are metamorphic rocks in the paleoenvironmental diagram I added, schists or so. In your simplification you missed there is a basement fault too.